# Codeigniter: Simple echo of data from DB

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model

What is the best way to create my model so I can call it from my controller like this?

`$this->model_model->function->dbname`

I have the following model but its rubbish:

**Model:**

```
function systemName()
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT cms_name FROM options");

    return $query->result();
}
```

**Update:**

```
function systemOptions($options)
{   
    $this->db->select($options);

    $query = $this->db->get('options');

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to?  Why not call it like this?:

```
 $this->model_model->functionname('dbname');
```

---

A complete skeleton of a model is like this:

```
<?php
class Mymodel extends Model
{
    function get_some_entries($number_rows)
    {
            return $result = $this -> db -> query("SELECT id, name
                                            FROM tablename
                                            LIMIT $number_rows");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thats better but I just get Array in my view.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie:  I updated it with a skeleton.  Adapt as needed.

Comment: I have updated my question but it just seems to give me the id why?

Answer (score 0):

Best way? You can probably read on CodeIgniter [general guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading) and alter to your situation. But the basic idea is that, you create the model class then load from your controller. Then just call the model function accordingly. For example,

```
class Custom_model extends CI_Model {


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function systemName()
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT cms_name FROM options");
    return $query->result();
}

...
...

function systemOptions($options)
{   
    $this->db->select($options);

    $query = $this->db->get('options');

    return $query->num_rows();
}


}

<?php
class CustomController extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();       
    $this->load->model('custom_model', 'fubar');
}

public function index()
{
    $result = $this->fubar->systemName('dbname'); 
    print_r ($result);
}

}
?>
```